# SQL Query with CASE and MAX value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Customers have the ability to purchase multiple products, and I have created the  query below that calculates the usage for each customer product by Workload. And it works.

However, how do I go about selecting the Workload with the highest Utilization?I've tried multiple ways but it doesn't appear to be working.

Here is what I get:
[image]

Here is what I want:
[image]

```
with Usage as
    (
        select 
            [ID]
            ,[Workload]
            ,[QE]
            ,[EE]
            ,(CASE 
                WHEN QE <= 0 THEN '0'
                ELSE CAST([AE] as float) / [QE]
            END) as Utilization
        from [source].[Usage]
    )

select 
    O.[ID]
    ,O.[Workload]
    ,O.[QE]
    ,O.[EE]
    ,max(cast([Utilization] as decimal)) as 'Utilization'
FROM Usage O
Group by O.[ID], O.[Workload], O.[QE],O.[EE]
```

Comment: You should make an effort to be **consistent** with how you write the SQL keywords - *either* write them in all UPPERCASE (SELECT, FROM), or write them in all lowercase (select, from), or in mixed case (Select, From) - but please **pick one style** and then **stick to it** - don't mix all of them together!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use window functions.  Here is one way:

```
with Usage as (
      select [ID], [Workload], [QE], [EE],
             MAX(CASE WHEN QE <= 0 THEN 0 ELSE CAST([AE] as float) / NULLIF([QE], 0)
                 END) as Utilization
      from [source].[Usage] u
      group by [ID], [Workload], [QE], [EE]
     ) 
select u.*
from (select u.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by utilization desc) as seqnum
      from Usage u
     ) u
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am getting the following error message: "Divide by zero error encountered."